# How to prevent the element's wrapping in div?

Tags: html, css

I have a header that contains of three parts (divs). When I resize the browser's window the header elements are wrapping. The screen shots and code look as following:

[image]

[image]

1) HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="header-left-part">
            <div class="header-title-left-part">
                <a href="http://www.nestro.ru/ru/" target="_blank"><img src="../../Images/Zarubezneft.png" /></a>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="../../Images/50years.png" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="header-middle-part"></div>
        <div class="header-right-part">
            <div class="header-title-right-part-login">
                <a href="http://www.rvpetro.ru/" target="_blank">
                    <img src="../../Images/Rusvetpetro.png" />
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

2) CSS:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    min-width: 1200px;
    width: auto !important;
}

...

.container {
    position: relative;
}

.header
{
    position: absolute;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 110;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.header-left-part
{
    position: absolute;
    height: 40px;
    width: 25%;
    background: #eaaa00; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */    
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #fef9e7, #ffdb8b); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(right, #fef9e7, #ffdb8b); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #fef9e7, #ffdb8b); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #fef9e7, #ffdb8b); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
    white-space: normal;
}

.header-middle-part
{
    position: absolute;
    height: 40px;
    left: 25%;
    width: 50%;
    background: #eaaa00; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */    
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #ffdb8b, #b2a000); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(right, #ffdb8b, #b2a000); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #ffdb8b, #b2a000); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #ffdb8b, #b2a000); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    white-space: normal;
}

.header-right-part
{
    position: absolute;
    height: 40px;
    left: 75%;
    width: 25%;
    background: #EAAA00; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */    
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #b2a000, #138d75); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(right, #b2a000, #138d75); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #b2a000, #138d75); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #b2a000, #138d75); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
    color: white;
    white-space: normal;
}

.header-title-left-part
{
    float: left;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.header-title-middle-part-text
{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}

.header-title-right-part-login
{
    float: right;
    margin-right: 3px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

.title-right-main
{
    float: right;
    margin-right: 3px;
    margin-top: 1px;
}

.title-right-main-icons
{
    float: right;
    margin-right: 3px;
    margin-top: 12px;
}
```

How to fix it?

Comment: The problem is that you have not enough space to show the content, which is the reason it wraps. So the question is, what is your expectation of a "fix"? Hiding some content? Making the header itself a bit bigger? Maybe media queries can be helpful for you?

Comment: The expectation is to earn money without learning how something works. It is how Russia works at whole.

Comment: Maybe hiding content would fit.

Comment: You can use `@media only screen and (max-width:767px){}` to hide the section.

Comment: I've already fixed it by putting: min-width: 1200px; in "header" class. Thanks for suggestion Matthias and kravisingh.

Answer (score 0):

see this image use gradient only in header class

[check image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vwUe.jpg)

```
<div class="container">
<div class="header">
    <div class="header-left-part">
        <div class="header-title-left-part">
            <a href="http://www.nestro.ru/ru/" target="_blank"><img src="image-1.jpg" /></a>
            <img src="50-logo.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="header-middle-part">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</div>
    <div class="header-right-part">
        <div class="header-title-right-part-login">
            <a href="http://www.rvpetro.ru/" target="_blank">
                <img src="image-2.jpg" />
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can't use absolute **together header and his child's** like "header-left-part" ,"header-middle-part" , "header-right-part" only design parent on absolute and his child's on statics

```
    html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    min-width: 1200px;
    width: auto !important;
}

...

.container {
    position: relative;
}

.header
{
    position: absolute;
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 110;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background: #eaaa00; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */    
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #ffdb8b, #b2a000); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(right, #ffdb8b, #b2a000); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #ffdb8b, #b2a000); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #ffdb8b, #b2a000); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
}
.header-left-part
{   
    width: 25%;
    float:left;
}

.header-middle-part
{
    width: 50%;
    float:left;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.header-right-part
{
    width: 25%;
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: I've initially used only one header, but there was the requirement about the colors in gradient scale and that's why I use three divs.